# Evaluate the integrals

Tags: calculus, integration

I'm having trouble integrating these, all of these have to be done without a calculator. These are just a couple I have to do. I'm not really sure whether to just substitute with U or do integration by parts or whether to use trig identities to change them. Showing me how to answer any of these would help a lot

$$\tag{a}\int_0^{\pi\over 3}\sin^2{3x}dx$$

$$\tag{b}\int_0^{\pi\over 3}\tan^4{x}dx$$

$$\tag{c}\int\sin^4{3x}\cos^3{3x}dx$$

Comment: Hi and welcome to Math.SE. Please edit your question with [mathjax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). Also, I recommend you to try a bit. Try a substitution, try to integrate by parts. If we tell you exactly what to do, then you'll learn a minimum... It is mandatory on this site to show effort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT 1:**

For $\sin^2 (3x)$ use, $\sin^2x=\frac{1-\cos 2x}{2}$.

**HINT 2:**

For $\tan^4x$ use $\tan^2=\sec^2-1$ and $\frac{d\tan x}{dx}=\sec^2 x$.

**HINT 3:**

For $\sin ^4 3x\cos ^3 3x$ use $\cos ^2y=1-\sin^y$.

Comment: I got 1 and 3 but I dont get how I'm supposed to solve #2. the Sec^2 from the derivative doesnt cancel out the sec^2 - 1 from the identity

Comment: You have to break it into two parts.  $\tan^2 x\sec^2x-\tan^2x$.  The first is easy and the second is $\tan^2 x=\sec^2 x-1$.

Answer (score 1):

HINTS:

a) $$\int_{0}^{\pi/3}\sin^2(3x)dx=\int_{0}^{\pi/3}\frac{1-\cos (6x)}{2}dx=\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{\pi/3}dx-\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{\pi/3}\cos(6x)dx$$

b) $$\int_{0}^{\pi/3}\tan^4xdx=\int_{0}^{\pi/3}\tan^4x\frac{\sec^2 x}{\sec^2 x}dx$$$$=\int_{0}^{\pi/3}\frac{\tan^4 x\sec^2 x}{1+\tan^2 x}dx$$$$=\int_{0}^{\pi/3}\tan^2x\sec^2xdx-\int_{0}^{\pi/3}\sec^2xdx+\int_{0}^{\pi/3}\frac{\sec^2 x}{1+\tan^2 x}dx$$

c) $$\int \sin^4 (3x)\cos^3 (3x)dx=\int \sin^4 (3x)\cos^2 (3x)\cos (3x)dx$$$$=\int \sin^4 (3x)(1-\sin^2 (3x))\cos (3x)dx$$$$=\int \sin^4 (3x)\cos (3x)dx-\int \sin^6(3x)\cos (3x)dx$$

Answer (score 0):

For First Integral $\displaystyle I = \int \sin^2 3xdx..........(1)$

Now Let $\displaystyle J = \int \cos^2 3xdx.................(2)$

Now $\displaystyle J+I = \int 1dx = x+\mathcal{C_{1}}$

and $\displaystyle J-I = \int (\cos^2 3x-\sin^2 3x)dx = \int \cos 6xdx = \frac{\sin 6x}{6}+\mathcal{C_{2}}$

So we get $\displaystyle 2I = x-\frac{\sin 6x}{6}+\mathcal{C}\;,$ Where $\displaystyle \mathcal{C}= \mathcal{C_{1}}+\mathcal{C_{2}}$

So we get $\displaystyle I = \frac{x}{2}-\frac{\sin 6x}{12}+\mathcal{C_{3}}$

$(b)\;\;$ Let $\displaystyle \int \tan^{4}xdx\;,$ Now Let $\displaystyle \tan x= t\;,$ Then

$\displaystyle \sec^2 xdx = dt\Rightarrow dx = \frac{1}{1+\tan^2 x}dt = \frac{1}{1+t^2}dt$

So we get $\displaystyle I = \int\frac{t^4}{1+t^2}dt = \int\frac{(t^4-1)+1}{1+t^2}dt = \int\frac{(t^4-1)}{1+t^2}dt+\int\frac{1}{1+t^2}dt$

So we get $\displaystyle \int\frac{(t^2+1)\cdot (t^2-1)}{t^2+1}dt+\int\frac{1}{1+t^2}dt$

So we get $\displaystyle I = \frac{t^3}{3}-t+\tan^{-1}(t)+\mathcal{C}=\frac{(\tan x)^3}{3}-\tan x+\tan^{-1}(\tan x)+\mathcal{C}$